# Python code to retrieve Apple Warranty information using serial Numbers

Tags: python

I am an IT admin and would like to find the warranty information of my apple  devices easily. I found this Python code online and it is not working.

https://github.com/pudquick/pyMacWarranty

I have 100's of apple devices and I hope someone can help me write/fix python code to retrieve warranty information for all the devices quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it doesn't look like this is possible, as noted in the script you linked to:

```
# Version 2.1
# Apple has again changed the warranty lookup method and now redirects to
# a CAPTCHA protected page at https://checkcoverage.apple.com/
# As such, no "online" warranty status is now possible. All warranty
# information is now estimated.
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried some random user agents to see if they allow anything without the captcha but with no success.

Surprisingly the Safari user agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.20.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.4 Safari/533.20.27
```

Raises error:

```
MISSING_KEY:wc.check.err.browsernotsupported.header
MISSING_KEY:wc.check.err.browsernotsupported.blurb1
```

On top of that :

```
We’re Sorry
You’ve reached the code limit and we’re unable to complete your request. Please try again later.
Return to Apple Support site.
```

Conclusion: 
As the person above mentioned. It doesn't seem to be possible at this moment in time. They also block connections after certain number of tries so even if you find a solution to use their service without the captcha you will need to use proxy to check more than 10-20 warranties.